# recursive function in c# get a parameter

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm trying to get a parameter with this function...

```
public static int subsumer(string id,int acc,SqlConnection connection) 
{
    acc++;
    SqlCommand cercas = new SqlCommand("select * from common_relation where id_source ='" + id + "' AND type='@' ", connection);
    SqlDataReader leggsyn = null;
    leggsyn = cercas.ExecuteReader();

    int f = 0;
    while (leggsyn.Read()) 
    {
        f=  subsumer(leggsyn["id_target"].ToString(),acc,connection);
        if (acc <= f) 
        { 
            acc = f; 
        }  
    }

     //siamo arrivati alla fine
    return acc-1;
}
```

each cycle the parameter `acc` will increment and debugging i see that in my case it reach value 3, but in the final recursion i get always 0...i can't get it...thank you all

Comment: What do you mean by `parameter`? Also why are you using string concatenation instead of using a proper parameterized query? A single weird character in your inputs will cause problems. More interesting input may be  `1;DROP TABLE COMMON_RELATION;--`

Comment: How are you calling the function?  Have you stepped through it in the debugger to make sure your logic is correct?

Comment: what is your function suppose to do ? sum or max ?
because i see only assignation in your loop 
no incrementation

Comment: i'm calling this function this way
int fuffa = DistanzaParole.subsumer("n#00004123", 0, connection);
it is supposed to give me the max acc it can reach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By returning `acc - 1`, you are decrementing `f` returned by your recursive call and I don't think that's what you expect.

```
public static int subsumer(string id,int acc,SqlConnection connection) 
{
    SqlCommand cercas = new SqlCommand("select * from common_relation where id_source ='" + id + "' AND type='@' ", connection);
    SqlDataReader leggsyn = null;
    leggsyn = cercas.ExecuteReader();

    int f = 0;
    while (leggsyn.Read()) 
    {
        f=  subsumer(leggsyn["id_target"].ToString(),acc + 1,connection);
        if (acc <= f) 
        { 
            acc = f; 
        }  
    }

     //siamo arrivati alla fine
    return acc;
}
```

On a side note, querying recursively isn't a good design choice. Querying recursively with readers open for each call on the stack is even worse. Not using query parmeters is also a bad thing.

Comment: ok now i finally get it! i know query recursively isn't a good choise, i'm not an expert developer and i'm facing sentence similarity with wordnet and some other stuff that it isn't properly an "hello world".
How can i use query parameters?

Comment: @Lorenzo, search existing questions or post a new one containing your query and asking how you can parameterize it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass acc by reference. I.e use: `public static int subsumer(string id,ref int acc,SqlConnection connection) {`

Comment: The function is returning `acc-1` so using `ref` should not be necessary (unless the OP is calling it incorrectly).

Comment: i'm calling this way
int fuffa = DistanzaParole.subsumer("n#00004123", 0, connection);

Answer (score 0):

The method increments at the beginning, and decrements at the end, therefore it seems you will always end up at the initial call value of acc (in your case, 0).

Comment: it is not supposed to increment in:

  f=   subsumer(leggsyn["id_target"].ToString(),acc,connection);


                 if (acc <= f)
                 {

                     acc = f;
                 } ?

Comment: It will increment when acc++, then when there are no records, it will return acc--, which means it returns the same value it was given.